# Multiple copies of the same file as a result of make / make install

Tags: unix, make

In a development project I'm involved in, we have some files in our src folder that don't need to be compiled (such as python files, a custom .bashrc script, etc...).  Running `make` copies these to our build folder, and running `make install` then (obviously!) copies them to the installation directory. That means we have three copies of the plain text files floating around on the system.

This doesn't really matter to us, the files are small, and the point of the custom .bashrc script is to make sure a users' system uses the installation directory to source everything (including custom python modules).

However, does this matter? Should we tidy up everything so that there aren't multiple copies of the same files? Or am I just being a bit OCD...?

Comment: `make` does not do any of this itself. It's the content of the `Makefile`, specifically the implementations of copying to build dir and of installing, that do it. That's something you (or your team mate) wrote and therefore can and should fix. Since we are talking about development, you should probably ask over on http://stackoverflow.com and describe content of your makefile.

Comment: @JanHudec Hmm, I assume there's a *very* subtle difference between saying `make` does not do it, it's the content of the `Makefile` - even though the `Makefile` only gets executed when `make` is run... __Should__ fix? Is this good practice? Or an opinion? If there're links to things giving best practice advice, I'd be interested in seeing them :)

Comment: The difference is not subtle at all, because those are completely different places to look for the problem.

Comment: As for the "should". It is best practice not to put anything in install directory that does not have to be there. For build directory it's not such a problem and some tools force you to do it. But it is better not to to avoid incidents where you edit the other copy than is used and wonder why the changes are not taking effect.

Comment: @JanHudec I obviously need to go and do a lot more reading - I'm struggling to understand the not so subtle difference... I'm also not clear what would be considered 'unnecessary' for the install folder, but is in the build folder. Since this is meant to be for users to download and install, I can't think of an occasion when a file in the build folder should be edited

Comment: Do you think that difference between C++ compiler and a program you write in C++ is subtle? Well, difference between _make_ and `Makefile` is exactly the same. `Makefile` is a program written in _make_ language.

Comment: For the rest, obviously it's not possible to say much about what your makefile should do when you didn't describe your project in any detail.

Answer (score 0):

Running `make clean` ought to tidy things up.